# AngularJs get request to download attached file

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I have an http get request that retrieve from backend a txt file as attached. The response arrives correctly with correct data, but the txt attached downloaded has incorrect value : [object Object].
The code in the success block is:

```
var file = new Blob([data],{type: "text/plain"}); // data here contains correctly the values
var fileURL = URL.createObjectURL(file);
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = fileURL;
a.target = '_blank';
a.download = idUser+'.txt';
document.body.appendChild(a);
a.click();
document.body.removeChild(a);
```

What's the correct way to see in the downloaded file the txt content?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whenever you see a object unexpectedly transforming into `"[object Object]"` in JavaScript, it usually means that somewhere along the way, something that expected a *string* has implicitly typecast your object into one (the result of which is `"[object Object]"` ).

In this case, it's because the Blob constructor ([as documented here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/Blob)) expected an array of USVStrings, not an array of objects. So to properly stringify your object, rewrite your first line to:

```js
var file = new Blob([JSON.stringify(data)],{type: "text/plain"});
```

That should solve your issue, but just as an additional tip, if this file is supposed to be human-readable at some point, you may want to call `JSON.stringify` with `JSON.stringify(data, null, '\t')` to prettify the file (see the third parameter of the [JSON.stringify documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify) for details).